# Why does here shifting by $+ \tau$ on one side implies shifting by $- \tau$ on the other?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, functions

I don't understand a part of the solution of an exercise and would be grateful if you could help.

---

Note: $\psi(t)$ and $x(t)$ are time continuous signals (german: "zeitkontinuierliche Signale"). The signal $\psi(t)$ is the same as in the Wavelet Transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform

The follwing equality needs to hold: 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)\frac{1}{a}\psi (\frac{\tau -t}{a}) d\tau \overset{!}{=} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau) d\tau$

So $h(t-\tau) \overset{!}{=} \frac{1}{a}\psi (\frac{\tau -t}{a})$, i.e. $h(t) \overset{!}{=} \frac{1}{a}\psi (\frac{-t}{a})$

---

My question is about the last equality, $h(t) \overset{!}{=} \frac{1}{a}\psi (\frac{-t}{a})$. Why does shifting $h(t-\tau)$ by $+ \tau$ implies shifting $\psi (\frac{\tau -t}{a})$ by $-\tau$ and not $+\tau \ $?

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: What is the function $\psi$? If we don't know, it could be all sorts of reasons

Comment: @Norse Ive edited my question. $\psi(t)$ and $x(t)$ are time continuous signals

Comment: What does the equal sign with $!$ over it mean?

Comment: @coffeemath Needs to be equal to

Comment: What's the difference between "needs to be equal to" and simply "is equal to"?

Comment: @coffeemath see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11077/what-does-above-mean or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926403/notation-for-should-be-equal-to

Comment: You can get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: @joriki Ah okay I didn't know Thanks. I'm used to always type single dollars but maybe double dollar is sometimes more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your emphasis is on "shifting", I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. But if $u=t-\tau  $, then  $\tau-t=-u $. It's just that substitution.

Comment: So the $t$ in the last equation is not the same $t$ as before, is that so ? Like $t_{new}=t_{old}- \tau$ thus $-t_{new}= \tau -t_{old}$ Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly. When you think about it, variable names are irrelevant, it's just a symbol.

Comment: Ah okay Thanks a lot for your help. I just find it really confusing that they don't tell us that they use the same variable names for different purposes in the same exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't shift the function, but the variable $t$: if you shift $t$ by $+\tau$, you get

$$t-\tau\rightarrow (t+\tau)-\tau=t$$
And
$$\tau-t\rightarrow\tau-(t+\tau)=-t$$